# Representing $x^3-2$ as a sum of two squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, sums-of-squares

> Prove that there exist infinitely many integers $x$ such that integer $P(x)=x^3-2$ is a sum of two squares of integers.

Ideally, I am looking for a proof method that also applies for other $P(x)$, such as, for example, $P(x)=x^3+x+1$.

For $x=4t+3$, $P=(4t+3)^3-2$ is $1$ modulo $4$. By a well-believed (but difficult) Bunyakovsky conjecture, $P$ is a prime infinitely often, and every prime that is $1$ modulo $4$ is a sum of two squares.

To find an unconditional proof, it suffices to find polynomials $A(t)$, $B(t)$ and $C(t)$ with rational coefficients such that $A(t)^2 + B(t)^2 = C(t)^3-2$. Are there any good heuristics to find such polynomials? Is there any computer algebra system that helps to guess a solution of a polynomial equation over $Q[t]$?

One way to guess $C(t)$ is to form a set $S$ of all integers up to (say) $10^5$ that are sums of two squares, and look for polynomials $C(t)$ such that $C(t)^3-2$ belong to $S$ for all small $t$. I then checked all polynomials of degree up to $4$ and coefficients up to $12$, and found, for example, a polynomial $D(t)=3 + 8 t + 12 t^2 + 8 t^3 + 4 t^4$ such that $D(t)^3-1$ is always a sum of two squares. But no $C(t)$ found in this range, and increasing the degree and/or coefficients  makes the enumeration infeasible. Are there methods to find a polynomial with all values in the given set, that are better than enumeration?

Comment: As a side note, your $D(t)^3-1$ factors as $a(t) b(t)  \overline{a}(t) \overline{b}(t)$ where $a(t) = t^2+2t+1+i$, $b(t) = 4t^4+8t^3+(12+2i)t^2+(8+2i)t+(3+2i)$, and the bar is complex conjugate. If you write $a(t) b(t) = u(t) + i v(t)$, then $u(t)^2+v(t)^2 = D(t)^3-1$. Unfortunately, I have no ideas about the main question.

Comment: One should be able to obtain a lower bound which tends to infinity, but not an asymptotic formula, for the number of integers $x$ such that $x^3 - 2$ is a product of at most $r$ primes (for some reasonable $r$, like $r = 11$ I think suffices), each of which is congruent to 1 mod 4. Each such number is then a sum of two squares.

Comment: @ Stanley Yao Xiao - do you have any reference to this result? I found paper by H.-E. RICHERT "SELBERG'S SIEVE WITH WEIGHTS" that, under some natural conditions on P, proves that P(n) has a bounded number of prime factors infinitely often. However, how to add the condition that all these factors are congruent to 1 modulo 4?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is similar to one provided [here.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2007167p14224750) The approach is elementary and proves stronger fact that it can be expressed as sum of two coprime squares.

We consider the product $(n+2)(n^3-2)$ which is equal to $n^{4}-2n+2n^3-4$.  Now we observe that $$(n+2)(n^3-2)=(n^2+n-7)^2+(13n^2+12n-53).$$
Proceeding as shown in the link we can easily get that $13n^2+12n-53$ is a perfect square for infinitely many $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ with first solution as $13(3^2)+12(3)-53=10^2$. If one chooses such a $n$ then clearly $n^3-2$ doesn't have any prime divisor of form $4k+3$ as $\gcd(n^2+n-7,13n^2+12n-53)\mid 25\cdot 59$ and $59$ doesn't divide $n^3-2$ if one looks at the general solution of the equation.
Since, $n^3-2$ doesn't have any prime divisor of form $4k+3$ and $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ we can infer from the folklore result that it can be expressed as sum of two coprime squares.

Comment: Alternative way to prove along the same lines is to set $n=m^2+2$ and notice that $$(m^2+2)^3-2 = (m^3 + 3m)^2 + (3m^2 + 6).$$ Then solutions to $3m^2 + 6 = k^2$ (starting with $(m,k)=(1,3)$) will give required $n$.

Comment: Indeed @Max Alekseyev though I won't edit it now in hopes that me or someone is able to carry out the argument.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev, yes, and then applying $m'=2m+k$, $k'=3m+2k$ gives larger solutions.

Comment: Thank you, Max Alekseyev! This solution is much shorter than in the answer, and this idea should work for many other polynomials!

Answer (score 3):

One more way to solve the problem. Let $x = 4t + 3$. Then
$$x^3 - 2 = 16t^2(4t + 9) + (108t + 25).$$
The system
$$4t + 9 = a^2 \qquad 108t + 25 = b^2$$
has infinitely many solutions. It is reduced to the equation $b^2 - 27a^2 = - 218$. Also we can consider a system
$$4t + 9 = ka^2 \qquad 108t + 25 = kb^2$$
with $k$ representable as a sum of two squares. It is reduced to the equation $b^2 - 27a^2 = - \frac{218}{k}$. There are solutions for $k = 109$.