# Representing integers as sums of three powers

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

A famous open question, discussed several times on MathOverFlow, asks [Which integers can be expressed as a sum of three cubes in infinitely many ways?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138886/). This is open even for $n=3$, that is, we do not know whether the equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=3$ has infinitely many integer solutions.

We also do not know whether the equation $x^4+y^4+1=z^2$ have a non-trivial solution, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/

The difficulties of these questions are related to the fact that $1/3+1/3+1/3=1/4+1/4+1/2=1$, hence heuristics predict that there are infinitely many integer solutions but they are rare. For example, the smallest solution to the second equation may have about 48 digits (see link above).

The problem should be much easier with the powers $a,b,c$ such that $1/a+1/b+1/c>1$, in which case heuristics predict many solutions. This is the case when $(a,b,c)$ is (up to permutation) equal to $(2,2,k)$ for $k\geq 2$ or $(2,3,k)$ for $3\leq k \leq 5$.

The case $(2,2,k)$ reduces to equation of the form $x^2+y^2=z^k+n$, that is, we need to check if $P(z)=z^k+n$ is a sum of two squares infinitely often. There are many methods for this problem, see e.g. [Representing $x^3-2$ as a sum of two squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409857/)

The case $(2,3,3)$ is the equation of the form $x^3+y^3=z^2+n$. After substitution $y=t-x$ for a new variable $t$, it reduces to $t^3 - 3 t^2 x + 3 t x^2=z^2+n$. For any fixed $t$ this equation is quadratic in $(x,z)$, can be reduced to Pell's equation, and, unless there are clear obstructions for solution existence, it should not be too difficult to find $t$ for which it has infinitely many integer solutions in $(x,z)$.

The next case is $(2,3,4)$, that is, equation of the form
$$
x^4+y^3=z^2+n.
$$
Are there known methods for proving that, for some given $n$, this equation has infinitely many integer solutions in $(x,y,z)$? As two concrete examples, is this true for $n=2$ and $n=-2$?

Some ideas:

- If we could find polynomials $P,Q,R$ is one variable $u$ with integer coefficients such that $P(u)^4+Q(u)^3=R(u)^2+n$, we would be done. But are there methods for finding such polynomials better than blind computer search?
- If we could find polynomials $P,Q,R$ is two variables $u,v$ such that $S=P^4+Q^3-R^2$ is quadratic of the form $S=au^2+buv+cv^2+$(linear terms) with $b^2-4ac>0$ and not a perfect square, we could then prove that $S(u,v)=n$ has infinitely many integer solutions in $(u,v)$.
- If we could find polynomials $P,Q$ in one variable $u$ such that $P^4+Q^3-n$ factorises as $R(u)^2\cdot S(u)$ with quadratic $S(u)$, then we could check if $S(u)=t^2$ has infinitely many integer solutions in $(t,u)$. But, once again, how to find such $P,Q$ other than blind search? Also, are there heuristic that checks whether such $P,Q$ are expected to exist at all?

Comment: quick note, there are infinitely many $n,$  positive and negative,  for which $x^2 + y^2 = z^9 + n$  has no solution.

Comment: There is a similar equation.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048092 There is only one problem with such equations. The degree of the equations is large. There are very few independent parameters. As a result, it is impossible to write a formula - because there can be a finite number of solutions. For a given number. The only way out is to guess some combination that will simplify the equation, but this is not always possible. There are few independent variables.

Comment: When $n=a^3$ then $x^4+y^3=z^2+n$ has a trivial solution $(x,y,z)=(b,a,b^2)$

Comment: Yes, that is why the smallest non-trivial cases are n equal to 2 and -2, as indicated in the question.